# Starting out with Umbraco 5.1

Tags: umbraco, orchardcms, umbraco5

Having never used a CMS system before, I'm just starting evaluating .net CMS systems, with the two most attractive options seemed to be Umbraco or Orchard.

Re Umbraco, I'd prefer to use the MVC flavoured v5, rather than spending lots of time learning XSLT for version 4.7, when that has come to the end of its development cycle. But, is now (May 2012, very soon after the release of 5.1) is actually a good time to start out on the Umbraco learning curve, as there doesn't seem to be the depth of support and documentation out there for v5 compared to v4? I'm sure it'll be improving all the time, but as it'll be my first CMS system, it seems a little scary leaping into a brand new, rapidly developing system.

Sorry for the subjectiveness / vagueness of the question, but any useful comments comparing the probable learning curves of Orchard and Umbraco 5.1 would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the above poster: You don't need to xslt with umbraco at all, v4.7 supports Razor.

Its a good time to start learning v5, but I would not promise any deadlines to clients any time soon. There are a lot of performance related issues that make it unsuitable for all but the smallest of sites right now - If your deadline is 6 months out, you could probably bank on V5 being stable by then, anything less than that, and you are better of sticking with 4.7, which is really fast, full-featured and a pleasure to work with.

Depending on the site, and if you stick with razor, the upgrade might not be that hard if you ever need to do it. I just spent about 3 months developing a v5 site, and because of the problems had to convert back to 4.7. The conversion wasn't that hard, and now being back in 4.7 makes really appreciate how stable it is.

Comment: Definitely test v5 before committing to any deadline.

Comment: That's really useful, thanks for the advice re being cautious about starting out with v5 now.

Answer (score 4):

4.7.x supports Razor - so you don't have to learn XSLT.

That being said, v5 is the future, and it is out, so I wouldn't bet my money on v4 for a new project. Check v5 out, read the bits of documentation that are available, and ask in the umbraco forums if you're stuck. Umbracians are friendly and do help each other out in the forums.

**EDIT**

[**Umbraco v5 has been discontinued**](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx) - you should not use it for any production site.

Comment: Thanks for that marapet, I hadn't initially realised that Razor was available in v4, i'm just off to have a play around with it now.

Answer (score 4):

You may already be aware of this but as of today (13th June 2012) Umbraco 5 is officially an abandoned project due to the fact it was fundamentally flawed at the architecural level and deemed unfixable.

It was announced at the Developer Conference... you can see the reasons why in the blog post below. Suffice to say, you're advised to not use it.

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx

or watch the rather cringeworthy keynote video here :

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/cg12-keynote-video.aspx

Comment: Ouch. Thanks for the warning. 

As it turned out the requirements for the CMS system we were implementing turned out to be relatively simple, so we're just writing it all ourselves (with the odd HTML editor and media picker & uploader component chucked in), and am now v glad we made this decision.